# Does function symmetric to y-axis imply local min/max at x=0?

Tags: derivatives, continuity

My question is as follows. Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\in C^1$ on a small neighborhood $(-\delta, \delta)$ around $0$, with $\delta>0$. Also there are two converging sequences $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^\infty\rightarrow 0$ and $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^\infty \rightarrow 0$ such that $\ \forall i, x_i < 0, y_i > 0 \text{ and } f(x_i) = f(y_i)$. Then can we prove that $0$ is a local min/max, i.e. $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x)|_{x=0} = 0$?

Comment: You can prove that the derivative is $0$, but there need not be a local extremum.

Comment: Having derivative equal to $0$ is *not* the same as having a local minimum or maximum.

Comment: A proof by contradiction should work. Assume $f^\prime(0)=m> 0$ and use the limit definition of the derivative (and the epsilon-delta definition of that limit) to prove that $\{f(x_i)\}$ is eventually always negative while $\{f(y_i)\}$ is eventually always positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a local min/max at $x=0$ is *not* equivalent to having zero derivative (also, you should use $\frac{d}{dx}$, not $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, because there are derivatives, not partial derivatives).  Also, note that your condition does *not* imply "symmetric to $y$-axis".

To give an example satisfying your conditions as written in the problem, take
$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)&\text{if }x\neq 0,\\
0 &\text{if }x=0.
\end{array}\right.$$
It is well-known that $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$, with derivative equal to $0$; it is also clear that $f(x)$ does not have a local maximum or a local minimum at $0$, since $f(0)=0$ but $f$ takes both positive and negative values arbitrarily close to $0$. Finally, you can take $x_n = -\frac{1}{n\pi}$ and $y_n=\frac{1}{n\pi}$  to get the sequences satisfying your conditions.

Replacing the $f(x)$ with
$$g(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{x}{|x|}x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) &\text{if }x\neq 0,\\
0 &\text{if }x=0,
\end{array}\right.$$
likewise gives a function that is differentiable everywhere, has value $0$ at $0$,, *is even* (so it *is* symmetric about the $y$-axis), but takes both positive and negative values arbitrarily close to $0$ and so does not have a local extreme at $x=0$.

To prove that the derivative at $0$ will be $0$, however, we have:
$$\begin{align*}
f'_+(0) &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(y_n)-f(0)}{y_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(x_n)-f(0)}{y_n},\\
f'_-(0) &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x_n)-f(0)}{x_n}.
\end{align*}$$
Since $f$ is  differentiable at $0$, both limits exist and are equal. If $f'_+(0)\gt 0$, then for $n$ sufficiently large we must have $f(x_n)-f(0)\gt  0$ (since $y_n\gt 0$), but then $f'_-(0)\leq 0$ because for $n$ sufficiently large, $f(x_n)-f(0)\gt 0$ and $x_n\lt 0$.  This is impossible. A symmetric argument shows that we cannot have $f'_-(0)\lt 0$. Thus, $f'_-(0)=f'_+(0)=0=f'(0)$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It is very informative.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly true that $f'(0)=0$, because $f'$ is continuous at $0$ by hypothesis and any sequence $\xi_i\in(x_i,y_i)$ coming from Rolle's theorem satisfies $f'(\xi_i)=0$ for all $i$ and $\xi_i\to 0$.

Notice however that $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x=0\\ e^{-x^{-2}}\sin \frac1{x^2}&\text{if }x\ne 0\end{cases}$$

satisfies your hypothesis (whatever they are), but $0$ is neither a local maximum nor a local minimum.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's really helpful and clear.